# Procedure or function “” expects parameter '', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL and trying to write a stored procedure. I am having some difficulties to get default values as an output result.

I have 2 table:

**Student_Input**:

```
InputID SectionID  ParameterName    Sequence
------------------------------------------------     
  1     100        FirstName           1 
  2     100        MiddleName          2  
  3     100        LastName            3
```

**Student_Input_details**:

```
ParameterName   ParameterValue      DefaultValue
-----------------------------------------------------     
FirstName          John                  1    
FirstName          Troy                  0
FirstName          Mark                  0
```

I am trying to call `ParameterName` from `Student_Input` and Its default value from `Student_Input_Details` as an output in one table. I am trying with following query but I am getting following error:

> *Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Getparameterdefaultvalues, Line 0
>
>   Procedure or function 'Getparameterdefaultvalues' expects parameter '@ParameterValue', which was not supplied.*

I am sure I am missing something important here.

My query is below. I am learning , it may be an easy question. Thx........

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Getparameterdefaultvalues
(
    @ParameterName varchar(50) ,
    @ParameterValue varchar(50) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @ParameterValue = DefaultValue FROM ParameterInput_Values
    WHERE ParameterName=@ParameterName 
END
DECLARE @ParameterValue varchar(50) 
EXEC Getparameterdefaultvalues @ParameterName = 1, @ParameterValue OUTPUT
PRINT 'Result is: ' + @ParameterValue
```

I need result like (i.e. `ParameterName` should only display its default value at runtime):

```
ParameterName   ParameterValue      
---------------------------------- 
FirstName         John
```

I have tried on other blogs but couldn't resolve this. Apologies If my question is not so cleared. Any help would be great!! Thx

Comment: Please use the {} button to properly format code samples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty simple and easy: your stored procedure expects **two parameters** - `@ParameterName` and `@ParameterValue` - but your call only supplies **one**...

You should call your stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @ParameterValue varchar(50) 

EXEC Getparameterdefaultvalues @ParameterName = 1, @ParameterValue = @ParameterValue OUTPUT

PRINT 'Result is: ' + @ParameterValue
```

Also: you're returning the retrieved value as an **output parameter** - so you're getting back a single value into a variable - you're not getting back a result set (rows/columns).

Comment: Hi, I tried with your query but I am getting following error: (Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.)...........

Comment: @Joy1979: updated my response - which **version** of SQL Server are you using??